# How to change values in a json file using JsonPath in python

Tags: python, jsonpath

I have the following Json file: car_models.json

```
{
   "name":"John",
   "age":30,
   "cars":
   [
     {
       "car_model": "Mustang",
       "car_brand": "Ford"
     },
     {
       "car_model": "cx-5",
       "car_brand": "Mazda"
     }
   ] 
}
```

I have another json file data_change.json, which contains details about the jsonpath and their values:

```
{
  "testcase_ID": "test_1A",
  "description": "Some description",
  "request_change_data": [
    {
      "element_path": "$.cars.[0].car_model",
      "element_value": "focus"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to read the data_change.json content, use the element_path from here, parse through car_models.json and update its value to the value from data_change.json.
As in, I want to use the jsonPath - $cars[0].car_model, parse through car_models.json, and change the value of car_model from Mustang to focus. So my updated car_models.json should be the following:

```
   {
       "name":"John",
       "age":30,
       "cars":
       [
         {
           "car_model": "focus",
           "car_brand": "Ford"
         },
         {
           "car_model": "cx-5",
           "car_brand": "Mazda"
         } 
       ]
    }
```

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

guessing that the Expected answer needs to have "focus" and not "ford"

The following should give you this:

```
import json
import re

with open('cars_model.json') as f:
    cars_model = json.load(f)
with open('data_change.json') as f:
    data_change = json.load(f)

for elements in data_change['request_change_data']:
    element_path = elements['element_path']
    #Reg ex to get you the number (as a string) between the square brackets
    position_match = re.match(r"^.*\[(.*)\].*$", element_path)
    position = int(position_match.group(1))
    print position
    # Split on "period" to get the thing to match
    thing_to_change = element_path.split(".")[1]
    print thing_to_change
    value = elements['element_value']
    print value
    cars_model['cars'][0][thing_to_change] = value

print cars_model
```